# How to handle CreateUserWizard Steps in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have used asp.net creatuserwizard in my project. And my custom template looks like this

```
<WizardSteps>
    <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep0" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
          //my custom code is here
        </ContentTemplate>
        <CustomNavigationTemplate>
        </CustomNavigationTemplate>
    </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
```

Now, in Step2 i have code like this;

```
 <asp:WizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server" AllowReturn="False"             StepType="Step">
        <div class="accountInfo">
            <fieldset class="register">
                   <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="City">City:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="City" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="CountryLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Country">Country:</asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Country" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
                    </p>

            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </asp:WizardStep>
```

So, my question is, how do i insert 'City' textbox value in my user profile as i click on next in step2.

Comment: i have read this, but it says everything is created in first step i-e "<asp:CreateUserStep>" while i want to handle the code written in <asp:WizrdStep>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the NextButtonClick of the Create User Wizard and check for the currentstepindex:

```
    protected void YourCreateUserWizard_NextButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CurrentStepIndex == YourStepIndex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add code to handle the `CreatedUser` event of the wizard control.

This part should be in the code behind, there you have access to the current state of the wizard:

```
protected void CreateUserWizard_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Finde the value
  var cityField = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard.CreateUserWizardStep1.FindControl("City");

  // use the field value todo whatever you want    
}
```

Comment: I have tried this one also. This code doesn't save the profile setting i-e City. My code only works if i declare cityTextbox in step0 and call my code like this; _var cityField = (TextBox)CreateUserWizard.CreateUserWizardStep0.ContainerTempalate.FindControl("City");_